# Overworked on a Major Project Without Much Benefit to Me

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, salary, negotiation, company-culture

I've been working on a large project for the last 7 months. Been with the company for nearly 3 years. Work before this wasn't too bad. This project would bring in major business for my company, adding hundreds of new customers. I have put in many evenings and weekends on this project, as I am the sole developer of the team after the other developer left for greener pastures 2 months into the project.

After the other developer left I was promised a generous salary increase once the contract was signed. After 4 months of delays the contract has finally been signed with a continuation clause that would require another 2 months of evenings and weekends for me. I've lost a week on the estimate for this current run because another project went into dire concern, without them adjusting the contract.

Management doesn't seem to take my concerns for the salary increase seriously at the moment (until next FY most likely) and just keeps beating the "how important this opportunity is for the company" line. I have received a few small bonuses during this time, but no new resources to help will come for some time after most of this is said and done.

If I stop now they may lose the contract, but I feel taken advantage of. I might get the compensation I desire, but I feel like I will be seen as a problem to remove as soon as things die down if I have to keep pressing the issue. And it will be all for naught.

Am I off to be upset for not being compensated until I pour another 2 months of my life into this project (hoping there aren't anymore gotchas)? I have a considerable amount of leverage here for the time being. I just feel like a sucker for doing the job of 2-3 developers for the pay of one.

Comment: Odds are, they'll drag their feet on compensation for as long as you're willing to keep working there. Start looking for another gig. Who cares if they lose an "important opportunity". Your health and well-being is more important.

Comment: @gnat More like an exact duplicate... And the top answer there almost exactly applies here.

Comment: See also [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid?rq=1)

Comment: If the project is so important you'd think the company would give you a salary bump, or at least send a few devs to help you out.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as there is a specific message about the project being received. As I cannot add an answer, here's my answer. Stop doing overtime and document why - what they say about this project being important is not reinforced by their behavior. Either they are willing to pay you more or to pay for additional help or the project is not important.

Answer (score 1):

To be frank and blunt. I would suggest you to start exploring an exit door. I know it must be very tough for you to manage search hunt and tough job schedule. But yeah, Please do (but make sure there you won't get the same situation). If your Managers or higher authority would really be concerned about loosing contract and you are the sole developer then they would have given you hike. I will not say to put yourself in their shoes and analyze other aspects. (As you have already mentioned its a large project)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about whats happening, i read your issue fully and i feel for you.

My advice to you, is

Don't do what i did, when i was in a similar situation.

Blow off the handle, and let it frustrate you at the point were you can do perform you job anymore. That's in a nutshell what i experienced, and i'm sure it happens to a lot of people, depending on the character. Some people are as cool as ice, some are not.

If you really had enough which is understandably ok, then start thinking of an exit strategy.

If you haven't quite reach that stage yet, then try and speak to your manager again and give it one last chance before the next step.

However if you do speak to someone make sure your calm and concise, make some notes as to why you deserve a pay rise, regardless if they promised you one in the first place. Make yourself Invaluable to them but don't threaten that you are leaving.

If they say, you need to wait another 3 months before you get a pay rise, then try and negotiate a quicker one, like a month.

If things go south wait a few weeks and then start thinking about an exit strategy.

make sure the next company you apply and get a job doesn't carry the same issues that bother you with this one. Some people are happy working at such places, others Hate it. Its natural. If we all the same then we probably blow the whole planet up.

So find a place somewhere that you as a person fits in, and the place fits with you.

most important thing is to be Calm.

Good luck